# Объявления, кончающиеся вопросительным знаком

Tags: лексика

Можно ли назвать объявлением предложение, кончающееся знаком вопроса. Например, если человек становится в центре вагона и произносит: "Кто желает приобрести обложки на паспорта?" Можно ли мыслить это предложение в рамках одного из значений понятия "объявление"?

Answer (score 1):

Если обратиться к Словарю русского языка РАН Евгеньевой, то «объявление» — это:

> 2. **Сообщение, извещение о чем-л., доводимое до всеобщего сведения, помещенное где-л. для широкого ознакомления.** *Дать объявление в
>    газету. Передача объявлений по радио. Вступительная лекция была
>    назначена на второе декабря, и об этом было вывешено объявление в
>    университетском коридоре.* Чехов, Черный монах.

Если рассматривать объявление, как сообщение, извещение о чем-либо, доводимое до всеобщего сведения, то, я думаю, *«Кто желает приобрести обложки на паспорта?»* можно считать объявлением.

Здесь возникают сомнения потому, что предложение похоже на вопрос. Но на самом деле это как риторический вопрос. Это сообщение, высказанное в форме вопроса, но по сути вопросом не являющееся.
Обычный вопрос задаётся с целью получить в ответ информацию. Тут такой цели нет. Тут цель — сообщить о том, что продаются обложки на паспорта и довести это до всеобщего сведения.

В форме вопроса это делается с целью манипуляции.

В вопросе присутствует пресуппозиция.

> ПРЕСУППОЗИ́ЦИЯ — лингв. неявный, подразумеваемый компонент высказывания, ложность которого делает всё высказывание неуместным или аномальным ([Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

Пресуппозицией в *«Кто желает приобрести обложки на паспорта?»* является *«Здесь присутствуют те, кто желает приобрести обложки на паспорта»*.

Вопрос не стоит: *«Есть ли тут те, кто желает приобрести обложки на паспорта?»* Тогда это был бы на самом деле вопрос, а не объявление.

Подразумевается высказыванием *«Кто желает приобрести обложки на паспорта?»*, что точно есть те, кто желает, надо чтоб они только себя назвали.

Таким образом, *«Кто желает приобрести обложки на паспорта?»* — это объявление, выраженное в форме, которую я бы назвал «манипулятивным риторическим вопросом».

Answer (score 0):

По сути это предложение. Операции «купля — продажа» предшествуют спрос и *предложение* (желание и возможность производителей предоставить для продажи те или иные товары и услуги, по определенным ценам, в определённый период времени).